# problemas con una tabla temporal

Tags: sql-server

cordial saludo para todos

antes que nada, cabe resaltar que lo que intento hacer es que por medio de unos querys dinámicos pueda insertar unos datos en dichas tablas para mejorar los tiempos de una consulta

```
            declare @FechaInicial datetime , @FechaFinal datetime
        set @FechaInicial='08/25/2016'set @FechaFinal= '08/31/2016'
 declare  @tbltmp nvarchar (max),@tbltmpila nvarchar (max)
        set @tbltmp='select id,
                CabezaId,EmpleadorTipoId,EmpleadorId,FechaComp,
                NumeroRadicacion,FechaRadicacion,TipoOperacionId,TipoCalificacionId,FechaDecla,PeriodoCotizacion,
                TipoAutoliquidacionId,PagoLiquido,TotalCotizantes,InteresesMora,SucursalEmpleador,
                FechaModificacion,IdEmpleador,idCabezaCorreccion,ExoneradoParafiscal,CotizantesSinValidar 
        into #tmp
        from Saludtot.dbo.Autoliquidacion_Cabeza with (nolock)'




        Set /*@Select = @Select*/ @tbltmp =@tbltmp + 
    '
     Where FechaDecla BetWeen '''+Convert(Varchar(23),@FechaInicial,21)+''' And '''+Convert(Varchar(23),@FechaFinal,21)+'''
    '
    set @tbltmpila=
    ' select
                pil.ID,pil.IDthRCArchivoProcesado,pil.NumeroRegistro
                ,pil.IDtpRCTipoRegistro,pil.CodigoFormato,pil.NitEps,pil.DigitoDeVerificacionEPS,pil.NombreAportante,pil.TipoDocumentoAportante
                ,pil.DocumentoAportante,pil.DigitoVerificacionAportante,pil.IDtpRCTipoAportante,pil.IDthRCPilaAportante,pil.CodigoCiudad
                ,pil.CodigoDepartamento,pil.Telefono,pil.FAX,pil.Email,pil.PeriodoPago,pil.CodigoARP,pil.IDtpRCTipoPlanilla
                ,pil.FechaPagoPilaCorreccion,pil.FechaPagoPila,pil.NumPilaCorreccion,pil.NumPila,pil.IDtpRCFormaPresentacion
                ,pil.CodigoSucursalAportante,pil.NombreSucursalAportante,pil.TotalCotizantes,pil.TotalAfiliadosEPS,pil.CodigoOperador,pil.IDtpRCModalidadPlanilla,pil.DiasMora,pil.NumRegistrosTipo2
                ,pil.IDtpRCClasePagadorPension,pil.ID_Autoliquidacion_Cabeza,pil.NuevoNumPila,pil.ID_Empleador,pil.PlanillaAProduccion,pil.PlanillaProcesada,pil.FechaMercantil
                ,pil.ExoneradoParafiscal,pil.CodigoDepartamento2,pil.ClaseAportante,pil.NaturalezaJuridica,pil.TipoPersona,pil.FecActualizacionArchT1
        into #tmpila 
        from   recaudo_outsourcing.dbo.thrcpilaencabezado pil
        inner join #tmp t on t.id  =pil.id'


    select @tbltmp select @tbltmpila


        exec  sp_executesql @tbltmp  
         exec  sp_executesql @tbltmpila

    --   drop table #tmp drop table #tmpila
```

pero me aparece este error:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(8962 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Invalid object name '#tmp'.
```

y es debido a que no localiza la tabla `#tmp`

que puedo hacer en este caso?

gracias de antemano

Comment: exec  sp_executesql @ tbltmp  Pero aqui solo mandas a llamar a esta o cuando mandas a llamar a @ tbltmpila falla?

Comment: ah perdón, debo editar el código,  le hago el exec a ambos, el problema se genera en `@tbltmpila`

Comment: Puedes editar el codigo y ver como queda realmente creo saber cual es el problema

Comment: ya lo edité solo le faltaba el exec de `@tbltmpila`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que las tablas temporales locales (#Tabla) solo existen en el ámbito y sesión en el que se crean. Una vez terminado el primer `sp_executesql` se destruye la tabla y se pierde hasta que vuelva a ser creada.

Para solucionar el problema, puedes combinar ambas consultas en una misma o crear la tablas desde la consulta principal para que estén disponibles en todas las llamadas que se hagan desde el mismo. La segunda opción puede ser más trabajo inicial, pero es algo más ordenado.

Fuente: [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables)

Comment: muchas gracias si me funcionó pero ahora tengo un problema, que necesito ambas variables que almacenan dicha consulta y cuando van a hacer la inserciónde los datos por la cuestion del `sp_executesql` no inserta nada en la segunda tabla, que podría hacer en ese caso ya que reitero, necesito ambas variables